# Add support for F# syntax highlighting

Tags: feature-request, syntax-highlighting

Currently [f#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/f%23) is not fully supported. F# on this site uses ML as Syntax Highlighting by default.

F# is a descendant from ML, but still is a lot different. For example, simple Line Comments for F# code don't get syntax highlighted, and are parsed as normal code:

```ml
(* hello fun for F# *)
let hello () =
    printfn "Hello, World!"

// hello fun for F#
let hello () =
    printfn "Hello, World!"
```

As the documentation of Stack Overflow states, it used `highlight.js` for code formatting. And this library supports F# as a language.

See: https://highlightjs.org/static/demo/ under: functional -> F#

In my opinion adding support for F# makes sense - it is probably one of the most wide-spread functional languages in use. And probably more often used than ML. Even if I don't have a proof for this claim.

As a language hint, the F# tag on a question could be used. To define code, the following tags probably makes sense:

1. lang-fs
2. lang-fsharp
3. fs
4. fsharp

Comment: C# uses "lang-cs", so using "lang-fs" would be consistent with that.

Comment: I'm all for this, but want to give a heads up that a [highly upvoted language-addition request on MSE was just \[status-deferred\]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/355928/julia-syntax-highlighting/368443#368443) in the name of the highlighter mechanism needing larger changes. It's very frustrating to me that the highlight system isn't getting more love sooner; [it really needs it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/355852/stop-guessing-auto-detecting-a-language-when-you-know-it-will-be-incorrect).